# how to get string between [LOOP]...[/LOOP]

Tags: php, regex

how to get string between [LOOP]...[/LOOP]
i try this but not work

```
$gloop = preg_replace('/\[LOOP\]([^\[]*)\[\/LOOP\]/', '\\1', $var);
```

...
string:

```
'<tr>
    [LOOP]<th scope="col">%Gdata_All%</th>[/LOOP]
</tr>'
```

but i would string in [LOOP]...[/LOOP]

Comment: Please have a look at a shortcode / BBCode library I authored: https://github.com/thunderer/Shortcode . It makes such things way easier to do.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I would first like to say, are you creating your own template library? There are some mature ones around like [Smarty](http://www.smarty.net/) which should be able to fill your requirements. This article by Jeff Atwood is also good read : "[Don't Reinvent The Wheel, Unless You Plan on Learning More About Wheels](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/archives/001145.html)"

If you want to roll your own solution then that is fine, here are some suggestions.

## BBCode

---

This method relies on having the BBCode extension installed with PHP, it is native and does not rely on the regular expression engine (slow). This solution will *probably* be the fastest.

You can have the BBCode parser convert

```
[LOOP]<td><?php print $row->title; ?></td>[/LOOP]
```

into

```
<?php foreach($result as $row): ?><td><?php print $row->title; ?></td><?php endforeach; ?>
```

Look into the BBCode arguments to learn about passing variables into your [LOOP] syntax.

You can view some more examples on the [bbcode_create](http://uk.php.net/manual/en/function.bbcode-create.php) method page.

## **Regular Expressions**

---

They are a little bit slower, but are enabled by default on all PHP installations.

Credits to go Gumbo for this regular expression (You should up-vote him).

```
/\[LOOP]((?:[^[]+|\[(?=\/LOOP]))*)\[\/LOOP]/
```

You can then use it as follows.

```
if (preg_match('%\[LOOP\]((?:[^[]+|\[(?=/LOOP\]))*)\[/LOOP\]%i', $subject, $result)) {
    # Successful match
    # You can access the content using $result[1];
} else {
    # Match attempt failed
}
```

-Mathew

Comment: With (.*?) it would still match "[LOOP]...[LOOP]...[/LOOP]". I think the OP had that part right: ([^\]]*). Assuming, of course, there can't be any brackets other than those in the tags. But that's a side issue; the real problem lay in trying to use preg_replace instead of preg_match. +1

Comment: Ah yes, good point. The regex posted by Gumbo below solves this issue.

Answer (score 1):

I would use this regular expression:

```
/\[LOOP]((?:[^[]+|\[(?=\/LOOP]))*)\[\/LOOP]/
```

It matches a sequence of any character other than `[` (`[^[]+`) or the `[` that is not followed by a `/LOOP]` (`\[(?!\/LOOP])`, `(?!`*`expr`*`)` is a negative look-ahead assertion) between a `[LOOP]` and `[/LOOP]`; the surrounding `(?:`*`expr`*`)` is a non-capturing grouping.

But it would certainly be better if you use a real parser to detect malformed code as [The Pixel Developer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/742735/how-to-get-string-between-loop-loop/742802#742802) already pointed out.